# CV Scheduled jobs not firing from cron

Tags: cron-job, scheduled-job, cv, sysadmin

I am attempting to use [CV](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) to call job.execute to run my scheduled tasks as described in the CiviCRM [Documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/). I am using Drupal 7. I have several independent sites running on the server.

It works fine when I call it manually (for each site):

```
sudo cv api job.execute --user=admin --cwd=/var/www/html/siteroot
```

The tasks also work when I call them manually from the UI (for all sites)

Crontab is set up with the following:

```
*/5 * * * * cv api job.execute --user=admin --cwd=/var/www/html/siteroot
```

the syslog shows no problems and that the cron fires (example output):

```
Nov  1 10:15:01 live CRON[8991]: (root) CMD (cv api job.execute --user=admin --cwd=/var/www/html/siteroot)
```

However,

the scheduled tasks appear to not be running. I have configured several to run "whenever cron is run" but they still do not run unless I fire them manually.

Is there something I am missing? Is there a log in Civi where I can see if the command is being received?

I am using Drupal 7, php7.0, CiviCRM 5.3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so this may seem like a silly issue to some but after some messing around I figured out cron didn't have access to the path where CV was installed so to fix it the crontab entry had to be changed to:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/cv api job.execute --user=admin --cwd=/var/www/html/siteroot
```

There was no error as the mailer deamon was not firing correctly so no error was being sent or logged.

Cron does not generally have access to the path that a shell root user does, which is why running the command `cv` as root works just fine.

Comment: debug suggestions here: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/sq974fi5c783xgu5dyisb6a6gw (probably would have led you to same solution, might be good for next time). also useful if you want to understand why cron environment is different to interactive environment - https://serverfault.com/questions/698577/why-is-the-cron-env-different-from-the-users-env or `man 5 crontab`

Comment: you probably want to NOT run your CiviCRM cron as the root user; it should run as the same system user as you usually run CiviCRM (eg httpd, www-data, or your web application run user). otherwise you'll end up with files owned by root which CiviCRM can't modify when running from web. see https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#choosing-an-os-user

Comment: I did not understand cron's environment at all - which is why I got confused. That was a very informative link thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is the user "admin" defined in Drupal? If not some commands will not fire under cv. cv needs a user under "username" that is recognized by Drupal as having the rights to fire the command you're interested in. I had this same issue myself which was fixed by identifying an authorized Drupal user.

Comment: Admin is defined in my case but that would probably be an issue for a lot of other people.